# Prove that this sequence converge.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am obliged to prove that this sequence:

$\large {a_n=(1+\frac{1}{3})(1+\frac{1}{9})(1+\frac{1}{27})...(1+\frac{1}{3^n})}$

is convergent sequence.

I mean I was thinking about this and I know that $\large\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+\frac{1}{3^n})=1 $
From this I know that it will be probably convergent sequence but I know that it is not well written proof, and probably does not prove anything. I would be glad for any tips how to prove this.

Comment: You can easily see that the sequence is monotonically increasing. If you can show it is bounded, you know it converges.

Comment: $(1+1/1)(1+1/2)(1+1/3)...$ has terms which tend to $1$ but does not converge..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\log$:
$$\log\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\log a_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\log(1+{1\over 2^k}) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\log(1+{1\over 2^k});$$
now, as
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}{\log(1+{1\over 2^k})\over{1\over 2^k}}=1,$$
the behavior of $\sum\log(1+{1\over 2^k})$ is the same that the behavior of $\sum {1\over 2^k}$, and this series is convergent (geometric with reason < 1).

(Edited for greater clarity)

Comment: So if $\large \log a_n$ is convergent that means that $a_n$ is convergent too? $\large \log a_n $ is a subsequence of $\large a_n$ ? This is what you meant?

Comment: (1) Yes, because $a_n=\exp\log(a_n)$ and $\exp$ is continuous. (2) $\log(a_n)$ isn't a subsequence of $a_n$.

Comment: Ok I now understand. Thank you !

Comment: But why you are taking $ \large \log\lim a_n = \lim\log a_n = \sum\log(1+{1\over 3^k}) $ why you assumed that $\large a_n=\frac{1}{3^k}$ ?

Comment: $a_n$=product, $\log a_n$=sum $\log$s of factors ($(1+1/3^k)$ each).

Comment: Ok I see this, I forgot how about summing logarithms...

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac1{3^n})=1$ is only a *necessary* condition for convergence of the infinite product.

*Hint:* Have a look at the logarithm of the product and observe that for $x>0$ we have $0\le \ln(1+ x)\le x$.